# select and highlight the next sentence from QTextEdit on button click and show in QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

The aim is to select and highlight the next sentence on each click of QPushButton and shown that selected/highlighted sentence in the QLabel as well.

The minimum working code of my Python pyqt5 gui application is given below along with its output

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, 
    QWidget, 
    QMainWindow, 
    QTextEdit,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QPushButton,
    QLabel)

import lorem
s=lorem.sentence()
p=lorem.paragraph()

t=lorem.text()

class myWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myWindow,self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('application')
        self.setGeometry(200,200,800,600)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # Cannot set QxxLayout directly on the QMainWindow
        # Need to create a QWidget and set it as the central widget
        widget = QWidget()
        layout=QVBoxLayout()
        #self.setLayout(layout)
        self.textbox=QTextEdit(self)
        #self.textbox.setGeometry(20,20,750,520)
        self.textbox.setText(t)
        layout.addWidget(self.textbox)

        self.l1=QLabel(self)
        #self.l1.setGeometry(260,560,20,20)
        self.l1.setText('highlited sentence')
        self.l1.adjustSize()
        layout.addWidget(self.l1)

        self.b1=QPushButton('next sentence',self)
        #self.b1.move(460,550)
        layout.addWidget(self.b1)
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

def mymain():
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=myWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=='__main__':
    mymain()
```

and the output is
[image: and the output is]

What I would like is: When the QPushButton is clicked, the first sentence of the text in QTextEdit box is selected and highlited and is also shown on the QLabel, and when the QPushButton is pressed again, the second sentence is selected/highlighted in QTextEdit box and is shown on the QLabel box, and the process continues.

What I have done is:

```
def next_sent(self):
    sentence = self.get_next_sen()
    #while(sentence in ["\n"," "]): #Filter
    #    sentence = self.get_next_sen()
    self.l1.setText(sentence)

def get_next_sen(self):
    cursor = self.textbox.textCursor()
    if(cursor.atEnd()):
        return "End Of document!"
    cursor.clearSelection()
    #cursor.movePosition(cursor.NextWord, cursor.KeepAnchor) # whole word
    cursor.select(cursor.LineUnderCursor) # whole line
    #cursor.movePosition(cursor.EndOfBlock, cursor.KeepAnchor) # whole paragaph
    self.textbox.setTextCursor(cursor)
    return cursor.selectedText()
```

and when the QPushButton is pressed

```
self.b1.clicked.connect(self.next_sent)
```

the output comes out to be

[image: the output after using the code]

Now, when i click on the next sentence button, it stays on the first line and do not increment to the next line.
also i want to stop at each line ending with dot "."

I am trying few things with `textbox.document().findBlockByLineNumber(n)`, but have not been able to crack this so far.

Comment: Your code just shows the ui, I see no attempt in trying to do what you're asking. Did you actually try something? Then, please show us what you did. Otherwise, sorry but this is not a tutorial website.

Comment: Don't use comments for code, [edit] the question!